Allan Variance integral for a first order Markov process
I am using Mathematica to solve this definite integral:
4*(q*T)^2*Integrate[(Sin[Pi*f*t])^4/(Pi*f*t)^2/(1 + (2*Pi*f*T)^2),
 {f, 0, Infinity}]

$T$ and $t$ are real positive. Mathematica is unable to solve this. In IEEE 952-1997, Annex C, equation C.16 the solution to this integral is given as:
$$(q*T)^2/t*[1-(T/2/t)*(3-Exp[-t/T]+Exp[-2*t/T]]$$
Is there a way to get Mathematica to solve this?

You can add Assumptions to Integrate:
4*(q T)^2 Integrate[(Sin[Pi  f  t])^4/(Pi  f  t)^2/(1 + (2 Pi  f*T)^2), 
 {f, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> T > 0 \[And] t > 0]

which takes a little while to evaluate and gives
(q^2 T^2 (2 t + (-3 + E^(-((2 t)/T)) (-1 + 4 E^(t/T))) T))/(2 t^2)

This isn't quite the same as the answer you give due to the factor 4 E^(t/T) in the Mathematica result instead of E^(t/T) needed to match your answer. Possibly a typo in the integrand -- when I copied the expression you gave, I had to edit it to insert spaces between the variable names.

This is a bug in Integrate because (q^2 T^2 (2 t + (-3 + E^(-((2 t)/T)) (-1 + 4 E^(t/T))) T))/(  2 t^2) /. {q -> 1., T -> 1, t -> 1} results in 0.168091 whereas NIntegrate[(Sin[        Pi   f   t])^4/(Pi   f   t)^2/(1 + (2  Pi   f*T)^2) /. {q -> 1,     T -> 1, t -> 1}, {f, 0, Infinity}] produces 0.0420228.

Is this a typo instead of a bug: your NIntegrate expression is missing the factor 4*(q  T)^2 that's outside the integral in the question. That factor equals 4 for your example of q=T=1

tad (@does not work): You are right. Taking into account that multiplier, both results are equal to  0.168091. Sorry for the trouble.
